# How to submit form after event.preventDefault();?

Tags: javascript

I have used  javascript to add this when a particular page get loaded.

```
document.getElementById('commit').addEventListener("click", validateSubmit,
                      false);
```

this validateSubmit method have some code which will validate form data and
it will do this

```
      function validateSubmit(){
           //some code
           window.addEventListener('submit', newsubmit, true);
           HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
           HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = newsubmit;
       }

       function newsubmit(event) {
           var target = event ? event.target : this;
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;

        }
```

so for the first time while submitting form by clicking its coming in this method and it is preventing form values to submit and after fixing al those values when i am again trying to click on submit button then its not working,in console i am getting this error-

```
      "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'preventDefault' of undefined"
```

Please help me...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to go through such pains to prevent user from submitting incomplete form. Try this:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" ....>
   <input type="text" id="txtName" />
</form>

function validateForm()
{
    //CHECK IF FORM FIELDS CONTAIN VALID VALUES?
    var formValid=....;//validation logic

    return formValid;
}
```

Now if during validation you find any error you will set `formValid` variable to `false` otherwise if all input is correct set `formValid` to `true. When form will get`false`as return value from`validateForm` function it will not submit.

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon but my problem is I have not added this code in html page itself . I have created an extension for Google chrome and which will first check for a particular URL and if that url found then when user try to click on submit button then below code comes into picture and then it will call validatesubmit function and for not to submitting the already filled values 
          "document.getElementById('commit').addEventListener("click", validateSubmit,false);"

I can not change the HTML page code.As that is not my website :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your function declaration from

```
function newsubmit(event) {
```

to

```
var newsubmit = function(event) {
```

the function has to be declared as a variable if you want to use it as a parameter of an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validateSubmit(){

           window.addEventListener('submit', newsubmit, true);
           HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = newsubmit;
           HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;

       }

       function newsubmit(event) {
           var target = event ? event.target : this;
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;

        }
```